# Email intent always launch gmail by default

Tags: android, email, android-intent

```
String body="message";

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check out this book I am reading");  
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");  
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

No matter what I do (removing all gmail accounts and signin a hotmail account with mail app), this code launches Gmail by default and do not show or let me choose my universal mail app.

**Consequently, there is no way to let user send email via hotmail or other mail provider.**

***update:***
Actually this is the best piece of code I ever come across, it presents you directly with an app chooser where only mail client are present. The answer below will give you a huge list of apps to choose from that are irrelevant.

```
String mailTo="";
Intent email_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto",mailTo, null)); 
email_intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject text here");
email_intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Body text here"); 

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email_intent, "Send email..."));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the correct MIME type (`text/plain`) instead of an invalid MIME type (`plain/text`).

Comment: thanks this works. But I am presented with all kinds of non-mail applications. How can I filter them.

Comment: @NubyJoe: You don't. The point of `ACTION_SEND` is to allow the user to share content by *format* (e.g., plain text). The *user* gets to control where, when, and how to share that content. If the user wants to post it as a tweet, or upload it to Dropbox, that is the *user's choice*, not yours. `ACTION_SEND` is not an "email `Intent`", any more than `ACTION_VIEW` is a "browser `Intent`".